# Comparing "Stockings", "Leggings", "Pantyhose" and "Tights"

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-request, word-meaning, difference

I was wondering what do you normally call each piece of clothing in the images below?
I have found the nouns "[stockings](https://www.google.com/amp/s/dictionary.cambridge.org/amp/english/stocking)", "[leggings](https://www.google.com/amp/s/dictionary.cambridge.org/amp/english/leggings)", "[pantyhose](https://www.google.com/amp/s/dictionary.cambridge.org/amp/english/pantyhose)" and "[tights](https://www.google.com/amp/s/dictionary.cambridge.org/amp/english/tights)", but dictionaries do not provide me with enough information to tell them apart!
Also, according to the dictionary definitions, they usually are used by women / girls, while if you google them, you'll immediately find out that they can be used for men as well. However, I have no idea whether the database of these webpages has been written by native speakers!
I would be appreciative if you do me a favor and help me to distinguish these words:

**Image 1**: (Men's sport short covering) and **Image 2**: (Women's sport short covering)

[image]   [image]

**Image 3**: (Men's long sport covering) and **Image 4**: (Women's long sport covering)

[image] [image]

**Image 5**: (Women's normal legs covering) and **Image 6**: (Women's transparent covering)

[image] [image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an American answer. Terminology might be different in other regions.

1 and 2: If meant  for cycling, they're called *cycling shorts*. If used for running or other sports they're called *compression shorts*.

3, 4, and 5: These are *tights*. When worn by women, they could also be called *leggings*.

6: These are *pantyhose* or *nylons*.

*Stockings* normally cover the lower leg and feet.

Comment: Only picture 4 is leggings, as they have no feet.

Answer (score 2):

This is a British answer.

*Tights* are a close-fitting opaque covering for the lower body and feet, worn by acrobats and ballet dancers, for example.

*Leggings* are similar, but don't cover the feet - now fashionable casual wear for women.

*Stockings* were originally (separate) knitted or fabric coverings for the feet and lower legs. In the 20th century, as women's skirts became shorter, they evolved into thigh-length transparent coverings held up with a (Br.) suspender belt or (Am.) garter belt.

Later in the century they evolved into the more comfortable all-in-one garment in your last picture. We Brits call them tights because they are the same shape as dancers' tights. Americans call them pantyhose (*hose* being another word for stockings).

Comment: Thank you @Kate Bunting. Then, could you possibly let me know what you normally call each picture in Britain (except #6 which as you mentioned you call them "tights".)

Comment: About the shorts, I'll go with what The Photon says. (3) tights, although the toes seem to be uncovered, (4) leggings (no feet!) (5) tights.

Comment: Everything you say re tights, leggings and stockings applies to American English as well. And we call pantyhose, tights too. Though if a dancer tights are not pantyhose.

Comment: @Lambie Oh - I had been given to understand that _tights/pantyhose_ was one of those 'separated by a common language' differences.